# Linearly Independent list of length 2

Tags: linear-algebra

A list $S$ of length $2$ is linearly independent if and only if neither vector is a scalar multiple of the other. I'm not entirely sure precisely how to show this, but here are my thoughts:

Let $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{V}$. Suppose there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{F}$  such that $$av_1 = bv_2. --(i)$$
Then subtracting the right hand side of (i), we obtain:

$av_1 - bv_2 = 0$.

If there is an inverse element $b^{-1} \in \mathbb{F}$, then the above can be arranged as:

$ (\frac{a}{b})v_1 = v_2 $.

For $b \neq 0$, $\frac{a}{b} = 1$ is only satisfied for $a = b$, which implies that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are scalar multiples of each other.

Where do I go from here?

From what I understand, if $a = b$, it must be that either $a \neq 0$ or $b \neq 0$, which would imply dependence, since $\text{span}(v_1,v_2) = 0$ for $a = b \neq 0$.

Added: and would I need to make another assumption, such as $av_1 \neq bv_2$ to show that $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent ?

Comment: By "A list of length 2" you seem to mean "two vectors" or even perhaps "a set with two vectors", right? Why then the odd name "list" and then "length"?

Comment: @DonAntonio A list containing two vector $v_1,v_2$. I do not mean set. By convention, the set $\{(0,1),(0,1),(1,0)\} = \{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ which makes the notion of linear independence a bit confusing. As for the terminology on length. The list of length $n$ contains $n$ vectors.

Comment: That seems to be pretty non-standard terminology, @St Vincent . You can either say "two vectors" (which are not necessarily different), or in order to avoid trivial cases you can say "set of two vectors" (because if it is the same vector twice then it is trivial and etc.)

Comment: I see. I guess I've been using the lists over sets because one my books has been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\Rightarrow)$ Assume that $v_{1},v_{2}\in\mathcal{V}$ are linearly independent. First neither of them are $0\in\mathcal{V}$. Then for all $b\in \mathbb{F}$, $b\neq 0$ $v_{1}+bv_{2}\neq 0$. Because there are no non trivial solutions to the homogeneous equation. Therefore for all $b\in \mathbb{F}$, $v_{1}\neq -bv_{2}$ so $v_{2}$ is not a scalar multiple of $v_{1}$

$(\Leftarrow)$ Should be the same. Just reorganize the argument above.